# Using a Sitecore CMS pipeline processor, how do I redirect a user based on their IP address?

Tags: c#, geolocation, ip, sitecore, pipeline

I am trying to do this with an httpRequestBegin pipeline processor, but I don't seem to be able to access the user's IP address from the given HttpRequestArgs parameter.

When I implement a class that has this method

```
public void Process(HttpRequestArgs args) {
    string ipAddress = args.Context.Request.UserHostAddress; // Not working
    string state = GetState(ipAddress); // already implemented elsewhere
    RedirectUserByState(state);  // already implemented elsewhere
}
```

I thought that this might hold the user's IP address

```
args.Context.Request.UserHostAddress
```

but it causes this error instead (stack trace says it originates from the Process method):

```
System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available in this context
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Edit, this is in Sitecore 6.1 and in the web.config at**

```
<pipelines>
<!--...-->
    <httpRequestBegin>
        <!--...-->
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
        <processor type="MySolution.Redirector, MySolution"/>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LayoutResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
        <!--...-->
    </httpRequestBegin>
    <!--...-->
</pipelines>
```

This server might be behind a load balancer.

**Edit 2:** It looks like I **was** trying to access both of these inside the Process() function and that is what was causing the error:

```
Sitecore.Context.Request
Sitecore.Context.Response
```

Comment: That should work fine (at least it does for me). Can you show us where in the config you are defining the pipeline? Also, are you behind a load-balancer?

Comment: Also, you may want to ensure that `GetState()` and `RedirectUserByState()` do not use HttpContext.Current.Request/Response. If they do, you'll want to pass the args.Context to those methods.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Neither of those methods use HttpContext.Current

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you defined your pipeline is fine. `args.Context.Request` should be available at this step in the request processing. The most likely cause is that this processor is being evoked under certain circumstances where the Context is not available. A simple check for the following should handle those cases:

```
if (args.Context != null)
{
    //....
}
```

The only other explanation I can think of is that `GetState()` or `RedirectUserByState()` are calling `HttpContext.Current` which is not available at this point (hence why Sitecore passes the context as an argument).

Also, a load-balancer would not explain the exceptions, but you may have better luck checking for the following server variables if the IP ends up always be the same:

```
args.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
args.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm sure this will stop the errors, but I'm not sure I will ever redirect a single user if the Context is always null.

I'm going to log every occurrence of a null context and every occurrence of a successful IP address redirect and report back.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's pretty normal for these pipelines to be evoked without a context. If you reflect the actual Sitecore pipelines, most of them have checks in place (although some differ depending on what's needed). For instance, some check for `Sitecore.Context.Item != null`, which would be a good way to ensure it's an actual user visiting an item and not some internal client request or resource.

Comment: I was using `Sitecore.Context.Request` and `Sitecore.Context.Response` lower down in the Process function. That was causing the error. Thanks for you help!